# How can I get terminal transparency with Tilda to work?

Tags: command-line, transparency, tilda

I like [Tilda](http://tilda.sourceforge.net/tildadoc.php) terminal, however it doesn't work well for me.

I installed it on desktop and laptop with the same settings and the same level of transparency - 50. The problem is on the desktop as a transparent background I do see the previous application, however on the laptop I see just the standard picture of my ubuntu desktop.

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Are both systems running Ubuntu with Unity (be careful, not Unity2D) or are you using different desktop environments? Tilda will only be able to use real transparency if the desktop environment supports composition.

Comment: @Glutanimate, you are right, I have mint with mate on the laptop, and fortunately mate has a way to apply the composition Widow Preferences -> Apply composition. Thank you very much!